# How to redirect logs of systemd to a file?

Tags: systemd, filebeat

I want redirect the logs of systemd to syslog or to a file that was readable by filebeat. I don't find a lot of things about this on Internet and I don't know how to do that.

Does someone have an idea and can help me ?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/mheese/journalbeat

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is available in the documentation that ships with `systemd`.

See `man journald.conf` on your system and read about `ForwardToSyslog=`.

To log to a file, you have a couple options. One is to forward to syslog and use syslog to forward to a file.

The other options are the `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=` directives documented in `man systemd.exec`.

They offer the ability to send output from a systemd unit directly to a `socket` or `file descriptor`. I don't recommend logging directly to a file descriptor, as log rotation can be a problem.

Comment: It's possible to forward to an other file that syslog ?